# Panel control with master forms and sub forms

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I need some helps on sub form control:

I am developing a C# windows form. The form is divided into two panels.  The left hand side panel contains several buttons and the right hand side panel is for displaying different forms.

So, when you click the buttons on the left panel, a corresponding form will be displyed on right panel.
E.g. Button1: ShowForm1, Button2: ShowForm2, Button3: ShowForm3

I am able to implement the situation mentioned above. But, I have not idea how to implement the following situation:
ShowForm3 is clicked so Form3 is displayed, then there is a button "ShowForm4" in Form3. If the button is clicked, then the form3 should be closed and Form4 should be shown in the panel.
I want Form4 shows in the panel rather than just a pop-up form (i.e. Form4.show()).
How can I do that?  Thanks.

My coding are as follows:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Master Form
        this.btn_show1.Click += new EventHandler(btn_show_Click);
        this.btn_show2.Click += new EventHandler(btn_show_Click);
        this.btn_show3.Click += new EventHandler(btn_show_Click);
    }

    void btn_show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Clear();
        int tag = Convert.ToInt32( (sender as Button).Tag);
        switch (tag)
        {
            case 1:
                Form1 frm1 = new Form1();                
                frm1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                frm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                frm1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                frm1.TopLevel = false;
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm1);
                frm1.Show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                frm2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                frm2.TopLevel = false;
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm2);
                frm2.Show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                frm3.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                frm3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                frm3.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                frm3.TopLevel = false;
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm3);
                frm3.Show();
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get `Panel` using `this.parent`. Write following code in `Button_Click` event of Form3.

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel mPanel = (Panel)this.Parent;
    this.Close();
    Form4 frm1 = new Form4();
    frm1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    frm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frm1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm1.TopLevel = false;
    mPanel.Controls.Add(frm1);
    frm1.Show();
}
```